# Update UIButton title from other view...?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am developing an iPad app. At some stage I need to use dropdown type functionality. So, I'm using UIPopoverView for the same.

When IBAction fire on tap of particular UIButton, I adjust popoverview rendering UITableViewController.

And all thing working fine. I need when user tap any of the cell, related cell value need to set in attached UIButton title.

[image]

Here, popover view is the UITableViewController view, which I create separately. And call it on select Outlet IBAction.

```
CGRect dropdownPosition = CGRectMake(self.btnOutlet.frame.origin.x, self.btnOutlet.frame.origin.y, self.btnOutlet.frame.size.width, self.btnOutlet.frame.size.height);
[pcDropdown presentPopoverFromRect:dropdownPosition inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Thanks

Comment: update your button text from the table view did select method

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes I want that thing. But I don't know how to achieve that. Please help me with some code.

Comment: Call delegate method from table view did select to your main view controller, pass the required information, then update the button inside the delegate method.

Comment: UITableViewCell *c = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [btnname setTitle:c.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: But how you can access btnname in this view, which is another view containing UITableViewController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sangony answer is almost correct, but with some minor changes, instead of register the method without parameters as observer, you should add it admitting one parameter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(someAction:)
                                             name:@"ButtonNeedsUpdate"
                                           object:nil];
```

Then, when you post the notification(in your table's view didSelectRow:atIndexPath:), you can add an object(a NSDictionay) as user info:

```
//...
NSDictionary *userInfoDictionary = @{@"newText":@"some text"};
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ButtonNeedsUpdate" 
                                                    object:self 
                                                  userInfo:userInfoDictionary];
//...
```

And then in the class that is observing for this notification, you can work with the data in the someAction action method like this:

```
-(void)someAction:(NSNotification)notification{
    NSString *textForTheButton = [[notification userInfo]objectForKey:@"newText"];
    [self.myButton setTitle:textForTheButton 
                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //...
}
```

Your's button title now should be "some text".

Comment: Elegant and simpler than setting up a Singleton.

Comment: Needs to remove self as observer or will crash.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the NSNotificationCenter. In the VC containing your button place this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(someAction)
                                                 name:@"ButtonNeedsUpdate"
                                               object:nil];

-(void)someAction {
// do stuff to your button
}
```

And in whatever other VC that causes the button to be modified, place this code to make a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ButtonNeedsUpdate" object:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But how can it recognize that which text has to be set, cause there is no parameter with **someAction**

Comment: You could set up a Singleton and use that to store your string(s) value(s) for the text label(s). I can post the code for that if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a delegate protocol with a method like `didSelectItemWithTitle:`. Make the view controller controlling the button the delegate of the view controller in the popover. When a row is selected notify the delegate which can then update the button.

```
// MainController.h
#include "PopupTableController.h"
@interface MainController : UIViewController <PopUpListDelegate>

// PopupTableController.h
@protocol PopUpListDelegate;
@interface PopupTableController : UITableViewController 
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <PopUpListDelegate> delegate;
...
@end

@protocol PopUpListDelegate 
-(void)didSelectItem:(NSUInteger)item;
@end

// PopupTableController.m
// in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
if (self.delegate) {
   [self.delegate didSelectItem:indexPath.row];
}

// MainController.m
// where you push the table view or prepareForSegue
popupTableController.delegate = self;

// and
-(void)didSelectItem:(NSInteger)item {
    // update the button based on item
}
```

Comment: I try your solution, but there is some error **self.delegate didSelectItem:indexPath.row];** told No known instance method for selector 'didSelectItem' in **PopupTableController.m** as well **incomplete implementation**.

Comment: You have to set the delegate and implement the method. It's all indicated above.

Comment: Thanks, it helps, but with this I can manage one UIButton title, actually there is more than one UIButton which call same UITableViewController...!?!

Comment: You can design the delegate notification any way you want. You can pass as much or as little data as desired. You can have more than one delegate callback methods.